# HiDPI support in Ubuntu Web-App

Tags: 15.04

I am using a Dell XPS 13 (mod. 9343, Early 2015) with a HiDPI screen.
All commmons application use a factor of 2

```
Firefox= layout.css.devPixelsPerPx;2 and layout.css.dpi;2

Chrome= google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=2

display= Ubuntu Settings / Display / Adjust... 2
```

Ok, great that's working without a magnifying glass but now what about the Web-App browser for Ubuntu?
Any ideas?